# How to trigger Agent Job As per condition using PowerShell in Azure Devops Pipeline

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have a PowerShell as below:

```
echo "Hello-World"
$MyVariable = "Proceed"
echo $MyVariable
```

What I want to do :

If the **MyVariable** is "**Proceed**" Only and only then Agent Job2 Should run

I have used PowerShell task and Given Variable name as MyVariableOutput 
[image]

I have done below configuration at Agent Job2 level

[image]

Can you please let me know how can I put these condition:

Only If the Powershell Script at Agent Job1 Produce the **Proceed** as the value of **MyVariable** 
Agent Job2 will run.

**Note: Agent Job1 and Agent Job2 Are the part of the same release pipeline**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you prefer to configure your pipeline with **GUI**, you must run script to add the **MyVariable** as **Variables** instead of a temporary variable by calling this [api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1). Because after the `agent job1` finished, the variable you just defined with `$MyVariable = "Proceed"` will not transfer to the next agent job. The `agent job1` and `agent job2` are independent with each other.

---

In agent job1:

Configure 2 powershell tasks.

**(1)** The first one is used to define a variable with value and set it as output variable:

```
echo "Hello-World"
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=MyVariable;isOutput=true]Proceed"
echo $MyVariable
```

Do not forget specify its `reference` name **MyVariableOutput** in this task.

**(2)** The second job is used to add this `output variable` into `Variables`, then the `agent job2` could access it:

```
$connectionToken="{token}"
$urlget = "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{org}/{project}/_apis/release/releases/$(Release.ReleaseId)?api-version=5.1"
$base64AuthInfo = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($connectionToken)"))
$getdef = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -Method GET -ContentType application/json -Uri $urlget 
##Write-Host Pipeline = $($getdef | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100)
$MyVariable=@"
    {
      "value": "$(MyVariableOutput.MyVariable)"
    }
"@
$getdef.variables | add-member -Name "MyVariable" -value (Convertfrom-Json $MyVariable) -MemberType NoteProperty -Force -PassThru

$getdef = $getdef | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100
$getdef | clip
$urlput = "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{org}/{project}/_apis/release/releases/$(Release.ReleaseId)?api-version=5.1"
$putdef = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $urlput -Method PUT -Body $getdef -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
```

The above script will create a variable `MyVariable` which its value is `Proceed`.

---

In `agent job2`, configure the condition as the shown below:

```
eq(variables['MyVariable'],'Proceed')
```

You can see the agent job2 can be run successfully since it has detect the value of `MyVariable` is `Proceed`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If the value of MyVariable is Proceed, why the Agent Job2 skipped? Agent Job2 needs to be executed if it get the value as proceed

Comment: @Eddie Forgive my mistake since my brain is still in Monday start-up sequence. Have updated then content and the scripts. Please check and free to correct me.

Comment: Thanks :-) It worked. Just wondering, Can we do this without setting up the environment variable withing the single-agent i.e both tasks are the part of the same agent.

Comment: @Eddie, if just pass the variable within tasks not agent jobs, don't need apply such complex scripts. Just pass the output variable as normal method: <reference name>.<variable name>

Comment: I have one more query regarding the same here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59370481/how-restrict-the-agent-job-to-run-only-if-specific-job-succeeded