# Azure Devops - not able to set variable in Powershell

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have an Azure Devops release pipeline (using the Classic Editor rather than yaml) and am having trouble setting a variable in an inline powershell script. The relevant part of the script is this:

```
Write-Host "Web is $web"
Write-Host "App is $app"

Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=MyWebEnv;]$web"
Write-Host "Set Web to $($MyWebEnv)"

Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=MyAppEnv;]$app"
Write-Host "Set App to $(MyAppEnv)"
```

The log files indicate that my `$web` and `$app` variables hold the correct values, however the setting is not working.

I've tried writing out the value in both the `$($env:MyWebEnv)` and `$(MyWebEnv)` formats and both formats indicate that the ADO variable has not been set correctly.

My variable is defined in the variables tab on the pipeline. It is set to Settable at queue time. I have tried with no value set in the definition and an initial value and I can see that the initial value does not get overwritten.

I've tried running this on both a self-hosted agent and an Azure Pipelines Hosted agent - same results. I have another release pipeline that does something similar without issues.

I'm trying to use the variable in a subsequent Stage.

I don't want to write the variable to a file or anything as I want to use the variable to control whether the stage even runs.

Edit:
Based on Levi's comment I tried adding `isOutput=true` and inspecting the variable in a subsequent step in the same stage - it's not visible even within a subsequent step:

[image: pipeline output]

=========================================================================
Edit 2:
I must have had a non visible character somewhere. I was composing the powershell in an external editor  (just so I had more space) and pasting into the inline textbox in ADO - when I typed in the exact same thing I had into the editor it started working - sort of.

I can set the variable now and it's appearing in the task below, but what I really want is to use it in the next stages - in the IIS deployment group to control that IIS server A runs, but IIS server B doesn't. I'm attempting to do this in the Additional Options Run Expression.

I've tried
`and(succeeded(), eq(variables['MyWebEnv'], 'myvalue')`

or (where MyOutput. is the name given to my output reference when setting the variable)
`and(succeeded(), eq(variables['MyOutpub.MyWebEnv'], 'myvalue')`
or
`and(succeeded(), eq(variables['MyOutpub_MyWebEnv'], 'myvalue')`

To clarify, I'm doing this on the IIS Deployment Group itself, and not on any of the tasks within that group.

I keep seeing that the deployment is skipped due to:
`Evaluating: eq(variables['MyOutput,MyWebEnv'], 'myvalue') Expanded: eq(Null, 'myvalue') Result: False`

Comment: Have you heard about [Json to Variable extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=OneLuckiDev.json2variable)? It helped me sometimes with variables across multiple stages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Levi Lu mentioned you can access pipeline variables in the next step. So if you set variables like this here:

[image]

```bsh
$web ="some-web"
$app ="some-app"

Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=MyWebEnv;]$web"
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=MyAppEnv;]$app"
```

then you can read them in this way:

[image]

```bsh
Write-Host "Set Web to $(MyWebEnv)"
Write-Host "Set App to $(MyAppEnv)"
```

[image]

And if you want to access them via env variables you should use this syntax:

```bsh
Write-Host "Set Web to $($env:MYWEBENV)"
Write-Host "Set App to $($env:MYAPPENV)"
```

**Answer for EDIT 2:**

What you actually need is output cross stage variables which is supported in YAML but not in classic pipelines. Please check this [topics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59369619/how-to-use-output-variables-in-release-pipeline). You can overcome this but it requires an extra effort as it shown [here](https://stefanstranger.github.io/2019/06/26/PassingVariablesfromStagetoStage/). However, please remember that you can't publish an artifact from release pipeline.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#dependencies) you have docs for cross stage variables but as above, it works on YAML.

Answer (score 9):

The variable you were trying to set in the powershell task will only take effect in the following tasks, which means if you echo out the variable in its own powershell task, it will not output the overriden value.  See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-a-job-scoped-variable-from-a-script).

> To set a variable from a script, you use the task.setvariable logging command. This doesn't update the environment variables, but it does make the new variable available to downstream steps within the same job.

So you can only refer to it in the downstream tasks by wrapping it around `$()`. See below:

```
steps:
- powershell: |
  
   Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=MyWebEnv]$web"

- powershell: |
     Write-Host "Set Web to $(MyWebEnv)"
```

If you want to use it in a subsequent stage. You will have to make the variable to be an output variable by using `isOutput=true`. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-a-multi-job-output-variable)

```
- powershell: |
      
       Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=MyWebEnv;isOutput=true]$web"
  name: MyVariable

- powershell: echo "$(MyVariable.MyWebEnv)"
```

You should also give this powershell task a name in order to refer to it in the following stages. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2020/sprint-168-update#azure-pipelines-1) to learn how to refer to multiple stage output variables.

```
variables:
   web: $[stageDependencies.stageName.jobName.outputs['stepName.variableName']]
```

You also need add [dependency](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/stages?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#specify-dependencies) on this stage for the following stages.

See below example:

```
stages:
- stage: VariableStage
  jobs:
  - job: VariableJob
    steps:
    - powershell: |
         $web = "---"
         Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=MyWebEnv;isOutput=true]$web"
      name: MyVariable

- stage:
  dependsOn: VariableStage
  variables:
    web: $[stageDependencies.VariableStage.VariableJob.outputs['MyVariable.MyWebEnv']]
  jobs:
  - job:
    steps:
    - powershell: echo "$(web)"
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @Levi - I have updated the question with a clarification that I'm using the classic editor and have also tried inspecting the variables in a subsequent step in the same stage - any idea's?

Comment: Hi @CiaranO'Neill If you make the variable to be an output variable.You should refer it within the same agent job by using the task name (ie. `$(TaskName.VariableName)`) For example: `Write-Host "Set App to $(Set-Env-Variables.MyAppEnv)" `. If you are using this variable within a agent job. You donot need to make it an output variable.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I've added an Edit 2, with some updated progress

Comment: I've added a UserVoice for this feature - please up vote if you think it would be a useful addition to Release pipelines - https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/1243075/pass-variables-between-stages-classic-editor.html