# How to retrieve Powershell variable across tasks?

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-tasks

I'm trying to set a Powershell variable in an Azure devops pipeline, then retrieve that variable in a subsequent task. But the variable cannot be found.

In the first Powershell task I've set the inline script to...

Install-Module -Name SqlServer -Force

```
$result = Invoke-Sqlcmd `
   -ConnectionString "Server=..." `
   -Query "SELECT TOP (1) work_item FROM ..."

Write-Host $result.work_item # This does write the expected value.

$lastWorkItem = $result.work_item
Write-Host $lastWorkItem # This does write the expected value.

Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=lastWorkItem;isOutput=true]$lastWorkItem"
```

And in a subsequent Powershell task I have simply...

```
Write-Host $(lastWorkItem)
```

Here is the result...

[image]

I've also tried...

- removing the `isOutput=true`
- retrieving it using `$(env:lastWorkItem)`
- using Powershell Core and 'legacy' Powershell

No difference.

What am I doing wrong? I've looked (very closely) at [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64657887/azure-devops-not-able-to-set-variable-in-powershell) and can't see any difference.

**UPDATE**
I'm using the classic pipelines, not YAML pipelines.

And if I try to store the variable without `##` (as per comment below)...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This example does not work. Check how to use output variables: [Use output variables from tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#use-output-variables-from-tasks)

```
steps:
- powershell: |
   $lastWorkItem = "1111"
   
   Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=lastWorkItem;isOutput=true]$lastWorkItem"
  displayName: 'PowerShell Script'

- powershell: 'Write-Host $(lastWorkItem)'
  displayName: 'PowerShell Script'
```

[image]

However, this should work. [Set variables in scripts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-variables-in-scripts)

```
steps:
- powershell: |
   $lastWorkItem = "1111"
   
   Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=lastWorkItem]$lastWorkItem"
  displayName: 'PowerShell Script'

- powershell: 'Write-Host $(lastWorkItem)'
  displayName: 'PowerShell Script'
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I should have said that I'm using a classic pipeline, not a YAML pipeline. This shouldn't make a difference to the Powershell command, however, and the command that you have tested and proven is exactly the same command that I have in the OP (although I have `isReadOnly=true`, though I've also explained that removing this makes no difference in my case.) So what's different about your working version and my task?

Comment: @awj I've tested that on the classic pipeline. yaml just for a simple view. The issues may be in your `$lastWorkItem`... is it some object or just a string? can you share the result of `Write-Host $lastWorkItem` in the first step?

Comment: As you can see in the OP, `$lastWorkItem` is the output of `Invoke-SqlCommand` - `$result` is the direct output from that command, then I obtain the desired value using `$result.work_item`. In the DB, that column is an `int` field.

Comment: @awj test what you see on the set variable task. Use write-host without `##` like: `Write-Host "vso[task.setvariable variable=lastWorkItem]$lastWorkItem"`

Comment: Ok, updated the OP with a second screenshot.

Comment: @awj why do you still use `isOutput=true`? It will not work at the same build stage....

Comment: Ok, I've removed the `isOuput=true` but it makes no difference.