# Pass variable from one stage to another in azure release pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have pipeline with [two stages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXu2J.png) and I need to transfer variable from first stage to second stage. I set output variable like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VN4qE.png) and in second stage I am calling it with name[**$out.abc**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsMEs.png). Am I calling variable with wrong name or there is another way how to do it?

Comment: Although it’s not possible to share variables across stages, there is a workaround. You can make it happen by saving the variable’s value to a file, publishing the file artifact to the pipeline and then reading the file in the other stage.

Comment: This answer may help you as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59369619/how-to-use-output-variables-in-release-pipeline

Answer (score 0):

You need to do steps below:

1.Create a Pipeline variable. E.g. named PipelineVar. $(abc) is variable in your screen.
[image]
2.Create a new inline powershell task

3.Use [Releases - Get Release](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/get-release?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP)

4.Use [Releases - Update Release](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/update-release?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP). Then read pipeline variable in second stage.

```
$ReleaseVariableName = 'PipelineVar'
$releaseurl = ('{0}{1}/_apis/release/releases/{2}?api-version=6.0' -f $($env:SYSTEM_TEAMFOUNDATIONSERVERURI), $($env:SYSTEM_TEAMPROJECTID), $($env:RELEASE_RELEASEID)  )
$Release = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $releaseurl -Method Get -Headers @{
    Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"
}
$release.variables.($ReleaseVariableName).value = "$(abc)" 

$json = @($release) | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $releaseurl -Method Put -Body $json -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN" }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do that with [AzFunc4DevOps](https://github.com/scale-tone/AzFunc4DevOps).

In Stage1 have a command line step, that outputs your variable into stdout:

```
steps:
- bash: |
echo '<AzFunc4DevOps.MyResult>my-value-123</AzFunc4DevOps.MyResult>'
displayName: Send a result value to AzFunc4DevOps
```

Then create an Azure Function that passes variable values to Stage2:

```
public static class PassVariablesBetweenReleaseStages
{
    [FunctionName(nameof(PassVariablesBetweenReleaseStages))]
    [return: ReleaseEnvironmentStatus(Project = "%TEAM_PROJECT_NAME%")]
    public static ReleaseEnvironmentStatus Run
    (
        [ReleaseEnvironmentStatusChangedTrigger
        (
            Project = "%TEAM_PROJECT_NAME%",
            ReleaseDefinitionId = "%RELEASE_DEFINITION_ID%",
            ToValue = "Succeeded"
        )] 
        ReleaseEnvironmentProxy succeededStage
    )
    {
        var nextStageNode = OrderedStageNames.Find(succeededStage.Name)?.Next;

        if (nextStageNode == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var nextStage = succeededStage.AllEnvironments[nextStageNode.Value];

        var nextStageStatus = new ReleaseEnvironmentStatus(nextStage.ReleaseId, nextStage.Id)
        {
            Status = EnvironmentStatus.InProgress
        };

        foreach (var resultValue in succeededStage.ResultValues)
        {
            nextStageStatus.Variables[resultValue.Key] = new ConfigurationVariableValue
            {
                Value = resultValue.Value
            };
        }

        return nextStageStatus;
    }

    static readonly LinkedList<string> OrderedStageNames = new LinkedList<string>(new[] {
        "Stage 1",
        "Stage 2",
        "Stage 3"
    });
}
```

(Internally AzFunc4DevOps will collect those variable values from Stage1 logs)

Then in Stage2 it should appear as a normal variable:

```
$ echo $MyResult
my-value-123
```

[Here is the full example](https://github.com/scale-tone/AzFunc4DevOps/blob/main/samples/PassVariablesBetweenReleaseStages.cs#L6).