# How Restrict the Agent Job to Run only if Specific Job succeeded

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

I have 3 Jobs in Azure Devops Release Pipeline :

- Agent job1
- Agent job2
- Agent job3

I want to configure **Agent job2** In such a way that it should run even if **Agent job1** Fails.

for that, I have set **Agent job2** property of **Run this job** to **even if the previous job fails**.

Now, I want to configure **Agent job3** in such a way that it should run only if **Agent job2** succeded

[image]

What configuration I need to make in Agent Job3 to make it Dependant on Agent Job2

Comment: You could call `Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=Job.Succed]$true"` in the end of **Agent Job 2** and read `$env:Job.Succed` (I think so) in **Agent Job 3**.

Comment: @MarTin : Can you please provide some reference examples for it ?? Also Where do I need to write `Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=Job.Succed]$true"` In Powershell ?

Comment: you mean something like this? [logging commands](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md)

Comment: @MarTin : Agent Job1 ,Agent Job2,Agent Job3 are different from each other so We cant send the variable across the agents

Comment: Why you do not but it in only one agent task?

Comment: @MarTin : Those are 3 different agent so we can't pass the value from one agent to another unless it's been set to environment variable using PUT rest Api

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT I want to achieve like this in one agent. so I want to run a task if specific previous tasks have succeeded. How to do this? Because if I try to divide into phases, then it calls `Get sources` again and all my changes are gone.

Answer (score 1):

> How Restrict the Agent Job to Run only if Specific Job succeeded

I am afraid there is no such out of box custom conditions to restrict the Agent Job to Run **only if Specific Job succeeded**.

**As workaround**, we could set a variable like `RunAgentJob3` to `False` in the Variables:

[image]

Then, add a inline powershell task at the end of your second agent job with condition Only `when all previous tasks have succeeded`, just after the copy task to **invoke REST API to update the variable like `RunAgentJob3` to `true`**:

```
$url = "https://dev.azure.com/<OrganizationName>/<ProjectName>/_apis/build/definitions/55?api-version=5.0"

Write-Host "URL: $url"
$pipeline = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{
    Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"
}
Write-Host "Pipeline = $($pipeline | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100)"

# Update an existing variable named RunAgentJob3to its new value true
$pipeline.variables.RunAgentJob3.value = "true"

####****************** update the modified object **************************
$json = @($pipeline) | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 99


$updatedef = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Put -Body $json -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"}
```

Reference: [Definitions - Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1)

In the Agent Job3, set the custom conditions to:

```
eq(variables['RunAgentJob3'],'true')
```

Now, the Agent Job3 will run only if the agent Job2 succeeded.

Hope this helps.